Windows API - Append a custom Icon to specific position on-top of a current Icon of Shortcut
I am familiar with the C++ and C# Windows API for creating a shortcut of a program on disk to the Desktop. As covered here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596642/Creating-a-shortcut-programmatically-in-Cplusplus
WshShellClass shellClass = new WshShellClass();
//Create Desktop Shortcut for Application Settings
string settingsLink = Path.Combine(desktopFolder, "Settings.lnk");
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shellClass.CreateShortcut(settingsLink);
shortcut.TargetPath = @"C:\Program Files\MorganTechSpace\MyAppSettings.exe";
shortcut.IconLocation = @"C:\Program Files\MorganTechSpace\settings.ico";
shortcut.Arguments = "arg1 arg2";
shortcut.Description = "Click to edit MorganApp settings";
shortcut.Save();

API:
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, [Out] StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, bool fCreate);
const int CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = 0x19;

How do I manipulate the icon for an existing desktop shortcut using Win32?

My Question: How do you append a smaller icon to an icon of a shortcut?

In this example, we see a small icon next to a open folder default icon. Or, the better example below:

